# Is there a way to load a csv/json file into a jar externally?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to load a json file into a jar file externally. This is a small spring boot application. This json file keeps on changing, so instead of bundling this inside the jar, I want to keep it outside so that there is no need to build the jar everytime this file changes.
Right now, I have my java jar command as below:`java -jar build/libs/my-customer-service.jar --app.build.number=1234 -Dloader.path=./config/PotentialCustomers.json --spring.config.location=./src/main/resources/my-customer-service-application.properties`
And I am accessing this file like below:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try (InputStream iStream = new ClassPathResource("PotentialCustomers.json").getURL().openStream()) {
        ObjectMapper am = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String,String> customerMap = am.readValue(iStream, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
        });
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    }
}
```

I am getting this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [PotentialCustomers.json] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
at com.jetblue.jbms.api.util.PhoneNumBlackListChecker.init(PhoneNumBlackListChecker.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
```

Comment: You could place the json anywhere you want and use its absolute path to read it, instead of using ClasspathResource

Comment: You don't need to keep the file in the classpath. Add a property to the app that represents the path to the file anywhere in the system. Then read the file when needed using standard mechanisms using the value of the property as a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first place, make sure you have folder structure like this ready.

```
./ - the root of your program
 |__ your_jar_file.jar
 |__ some_properties_file.properties
```

To access some_properties_file.properties  from code inside jar, use utility function like one below.

```
Properties appProperties = new Properties();
FileInputStream file;

String path = "./some_properties_file.properties";    
file = new FileInputStream(path);

appProperties .load(file);
String propValue= appProperties .getProperty("Property_Name");
```